Are Compactness for FOL and the Pumping Lemma for RL/CFL two instances of the same phenomenon?
As title states, I'm curious whether my intuition for the Compactness result for FOL and the Pumping Lemma for RL/CFL being two expressions expressions of the same phenomenon (that is: an attempt to capture the infinite through finitary means) might be wellfounded.
The idea is precisely that: In Compactness one gets that, due to the correspondence between the semantic, model-theoretic, infinitary POV and the syntactic, proof-theoretic, finitary POV, one can obtain certain models just by verifying the finite sections of a certain theory to hold. However, as "there is only so much 'information' one can process" through a finite derivation, one is ultimately able to "squeeze" in certain properties which "overflow" the finitary object (derivation) at hand.
Similarly, when one attempts to, for example, capture infinite languages (produced via regular expressions) through finitistic automata, one is quickly met with the fact that there is only so much "information" a finite number of states can "hold", so that a "big enough" sentence might be able to "go over" said threshold and "escape" the finitary attempt at fully capturing the infinite object in question.

I don't think there's more than a superficial similarity, to be honest.

No way. The compactness theorem states that a set of first-order sentences has a model if and only if every finite subset of it has a model. But the pumping lemma does not characterize regular languages.
